# Ubuntu 12.10 Disks - where is connect to server?

Tags: 12.10, storage

It use to be that when you ran 'Disk Utility' (up to 12.04) you had the option to connect to a remote server (running udisk) to view/manage storage. What happen to this feature?

What happened to this ability here:
http://code.duffy.jp/use-disk-utility-to-manage-remote-server-in-ubuntu-10-04/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option got canned, together with some other options, when disk utility was rewritten [bug #1004094](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1004094). Add yourself to the affected and hope it gets re-instated. Sorry.

You can still access it from the panel though (see 'file').